# Android Json parsing with multiple JsonArray's

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse JSON data which is like:

```
 {
      "name1": "xyz",
      "data":[{
          "education": {
            "School": "xyz",
             "ug": "xyz",
             "Activities": [{
              ...
             }],
            "Prizes": [{
            ...
            }],
            "Curriculum":[{
             ...
            }]
         }
      }]      
     }
```

How can I fetch the JSONArray of activities, prizes, curriculum values?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: do you just need the values or do you an object containing all the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the values of the first element (you are looking at an array so you may want all the elements) you can try this:

```
String src = " { ... } "; //your json
JSONObject mainObject= new JSONObject(src);
JSONArray dataArray= mainObject.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject firstDataObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(0); //get the first element
JSONObject educationObject = firstDataObject.getJSONObject("education");
JSONArray activitiesArray = educationObject.getJSONArray("Activities");
//do something with the array. Ex: activitiesArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray prizesArray = educationObject.getJSONArray("Prizes");
//do something with the array
JSONArray curriculumArray = educationObject.getJSONArray("Curriculum");
//do something with the array
```

Comment: Thank u  @Gianni B. :), this really helped me.